# installing caffe cmake error

Tags: cmake, caffe

I've followed all the steps to install the caffe dependencies. I've bumped into the following error:

```
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/FindPackageTest/Baz': No such file or directory
find: `1.1': No such file or directory
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/FindPackageTest/Baz': No such file or directory
find: `1.2': No such file or directory
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/FindPackageTest/Baz': No such file or directory
find: `1.2/CMake': No such file or directory
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/SubDirSpaces/Another': No such file or directory
find: `Subdir': No such file or directory
find: `Sources': No such file or directory
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `find dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/SubDirSpaces/Some(x86) Sources -maxdepth 1 \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.proto' \) | grep -q .'
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/SubDirSpaces/Some': No such file or directory
find: `Examples': No such file or directory
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/SubDirSpaces/Some': No such file or directory
find: `Examples/example2': No such file or directory
find: `dependencies/cmake-3.3.0-rc2/Tests/SubDirSpaces/Some': No such file or directory
find: `Examples/example1': No such file or directory
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a(gflags.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libgflags.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. It seems as if cmake hasn't been installed properly? What's curious is that I have two cmake folders: One in my caffe folder and the other one inside an extra folder I called "dependencies" in which I am compiling all other dependencies for caffe:

doing form my /caffe/ folder:

```
$ ls 

build
.build_release
caffe.cloc
cmake
cmake-3.3.0-rc2.tar.gz
CMakeLists.txt
CONTRIBUTORS.md
data
dependencies
distribute
docs
.Doxyfile
examples
.gitignore
include
INSTALL.md
LICENSE
Makefile
Makefile.config
Makefile.config.example
matlab
models
python
README.md
scripts
src
tools
.travis.yml
```

doing ls from my /caffe/dependencies/ folder:

```
$ ls

cmake-3.3.0-rc2
cmake-3.3.0-rc2.tar.gz
gflags-master
gflags-master.zip
glog-0.3.3
glog-0.3.3.tar.gz
master.zip
mdb
```

Was I supposed to install all the dependencies inside my /caffe/ folder?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use the `cmake-gui` for `making` Caffe. There you can set the appropriate paths easily. No need to install all the dependencies in the Caffe root directory. You may install them in your system home directory.